# Solidworks hollow/shell a STL Part

Tags: 3d, subtraction, solidworks

I'm pretty new at solidworks!! 
But I've been able to create a solid from a stl files. It's a Truncated tetrahedron shape.

Now I wanted this shape to be hollow (for 3D printing and adding threads).
So I've searched for a while and found a tutorial for the shell tool. This didn't work out because it gave me an error. That the faces may offset in adjacent spaces.

So I thought if I had one part and then a the same part but scale it 3mm. Place them on the same spot and then subtract them of some sort. It would give me the same shelled shape I want.

Would this work and does anybody know a way to do this or has a better way to hollow out my solid.

STL & PART upload.

[Files Google Drive](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B_MsHMgJBbmedHNtUXV5YnFWeHc&usp=sharing)

Comment: This is just silly I can't get this to work, how is it possible that I found nothing remotely similar to what I want to achieve.. Internet my friend why??

Comment: Did you try the SOLIDWORKS forums?  You aren't likely to get much help here on a programming based site.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have SOLIDWORKS Professional or Premium, you can use ScanTo3D to turn the part into a Solid / Surface body. At that point, you can manipulate the geometry as you would anything else in SOLIDWORKS.

Here's a video showing both turning on ScanTo3D and how to use it.

https://youtu.be/ZjzqWCfNfmQ

Answer (score 1):

> "So I thought if I had one part and then a the same part but scale it
>   3mm. Place them on the same spot and then subtract them of some sort.
>   It would give me the same shelled shape I want."

use the move/copy body command to copy it
use the scale command to scale it
use the combine feature to subject the smaller body from the main body

Alternatively use the check geometry feature to find any faulty faces and ALWAYS run import diagnostics on an imported body.  if you can find and fix a faulty face try the shell tool again.  If the minimum radius is too small then you will need to manually offset faces using the offset surface command